# How to get back a list from bytes in Python?

Tags: python, byte

I have a list in Python that I converted to bytes using `bytes()`. I want to get back that list and I am unsure how to do that. I searched around and it seemed to me like I can get back integers or strings not really the list itself. I am new to byte manipulation and maybe I am missing something obvious?

```
arr=[1,2,3,4,5]
arr2= bytes(arr)
```

I want to do something like `arr1= *list*.from_bytes(arr2)`, which I am expecting to return `arr1= [1,2,3,4,5]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the `bytes` string into `list()` to convert back:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> bytes(lst)
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05'
>>> list(bytes(lst))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```